# How to redirect a page request to another url

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-routing

I use url routing in my web application. I have changed my url routing rules and so all my links on the other sites will be broken after I release my web application. Here my old and new rule examples:

Old one:

```
http://domain/Urun/sungerbob-tamir-seti/6/0
```

New one:

```
 http://domain/sungerbob-tamir-seti/6/0
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Did you try modifying your 404 page to redirect?

Comment: Use url rewrite to remove `Urun`?